# Meaning of "sick-fit"

Tags: seventeenth-century-english

I recently came across with a religious text of the english Puritan theologian Edward Polhill (1622-1694). Here is a passage from it:

> "Satan may hold up his pardoned sins, as it were in their old guilt; the arrows of God may stick fast in him, and bring qualms and **sick-fits** upon his conscience: but at that day his comforts shall be unvariable; a nightless day, and a cloudless horizon;"

I would like to know the meaning of the word "sick-fits". I am not a native english speaker and could not find that idiom in any dictionary.

Comment: ...possibly a "fit" such as an epileptic seizure?

Comment: ...or just a 'fit' (short spell) of illness/nausea?

Comment: So troubled in the man's conscience that he feels/actually is physically ill.

Comment: I just saw a new one on the Chauvin trial coverage..."excited delirium".

Comment: I think it may be short for "fits of sickness".

Comment: Thank you all. I didn't know this meaning of the word "fit". It helped a lot.